# How to access the specific object in a nested array in java script

Tags: javascript, development-environment, thunderbird

[image: The screenshot of my code snippet].

I want to get `the[items] Array object` separately.
My doubt is that the `<value> object` generated from the function return and due to `<value> object` it is not indexing properly.

I tried these approaches:

1. `views.value.items` not working.
2. `views[0][items]`   not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`views` seems to be a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), that wraps the actual value you want. So you need to call the [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method on it and provide a callback that can use the value that is inside the Promise. Or if you are in an [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function, use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

I would recommend to read at least the two following pages, that describe how to use promises in the two mentioned ways:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Thank you very much for the information and it solved my issue, @user228011 ,

Answer (score 0):

As I understand views and value is an object. If so, you can use views.value.items[0]

It is better to check value type with `console.log(typeof views)`

Comment: i tried this "views.value.items[0]"  but it thrown an error    "views.value is undefined"   , also i checked the console.log(typeof views)  and output is 'object '..   i am doubting that the <value> in the views has any  other meaning  which we need to access ? which means specifying '< >' , because other object 'item' which does not have that enclose , just my doubt ?. expecting your reply and thank you very much in advance .

Comment: @ISMAIL, so did you finally solve your problem? Look like answer above should work for you

Comment: @ Sabit Rakhim , yes solved the issue , that answer worked for me, and thank you for your time and effort too.. :)